# how to work with double in textbox?

Tags: c#, variables, textbox

I would like to write a code that reads a time the user wrote into textbox1, lets say 09:00 (hh:mm), save it into a variable, then takes this variable and adds 08:40 to it and Outputs then the outcome 17:40 into textbox2.

The Problem is, when working with double it is working well, but I need to use the hh:mm - Format, I know some languages have the Option to declare a variable as time but it seems like c# isnt doing this. so whats the solution? 
thats my current code

```
    void CmdWriteClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string varstr = textbox_1.Text;
        double muss = 8.40;
        double vardb = Convert.ToDouble(varstr);
        double end = vardb + muss;
        textbox_2.Text = end.ToString();
    }
```

this would of course Output me double-numbers. so if varstr is 08.30 it would Output 16,7 when I Need to make it Output 17:10. Any help is appreciated

thank you guys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't be using a `TextBox` for this. You have a specific control to take care of dates and times: `DateTimePicker`.

Add one of these to your form. If you only want the user to modify the time, disallowing date changes, you can do the following:

```
public myForm()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    ....
    myDateTimePicker.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
    myDateTimePicker.CustomFormat = "HH:mm"; //Shows only hours and minutes in 24h format
    myDateTimePicker.Value = DateTime.Now.Date; //sets the time to today at 0:00
    myDateTimePicker.MinDate = DateTime.Now.Date;
    myDateTimePicker.MaxDate = DateTime.Now.Date.Add(new TimeSpan(23, 59, 59)); //User can't change date.
}

private DateTime newTime;
private void myDateTimePicker_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    newTime = myDateTimePicker.Value.AddHours(8.5);
}
```

Obviously if you want the user to set the date too, then simply change the `MinValue` and `MaxValue` restrictions to your requirements (if any) and choose one of the predefined format options instead of `DateTimePickerFormat.Custom`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
 dateValue.AddHours(8);
 dateValue.AddMinutes(30);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use DateTime instead of double.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DateTime dateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(textBox1.Text, "HH:mm", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
        TimeSpan time = new TimeSpan(8,40,0);
        DateTime outputTime = dateTime.Add(time);
        textBox2.Text = outputTime.ToString("HH:mm");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
string input = textbox_1.Text;
DateTime inputTime;
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(input, "HH:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out inputTime))
{
      DateTime outputTime=inputTime.AddHours(8).AddMinutes(40);
      textbox_2.Text = outputTime.ToString("HH:mm");
}
```

Basically, you parse the input string to a `DateTime` variable, add the time you need and then convert back to string to show it in your `TextBox`

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to do it with double, you have to think about the conversion from minutes to whole numbers. 8.4 would be then 60 * .4 = 24 minutes.

For the rest, the text string you can parse using `TimeSpan.Parse` and you can write a custom function that would parse the double to a TimeSpan and then simply add the 2 together, like so:

```
using System;

namespace TimeParser {
    class Program {
        static TimeSpan GetTimeFromText( string text ) {
            if ( string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace( text ) ) {
                return TimeSpan.Zero;
            }
            return TimeSpan.Parse( text );
        }

        static TimeSpan GetTimeFromDouble( double value ) {
            if ( value <= 0 ) {
                return TimeSpan.Zero;
            }
            int hours = (int)Math.Floor( value );
            int minutes = (int)(( value - hours )*60);
            return new TimeSpan(0, hours, minutes, 0);
        }

        static TimeSpan GetAddedTime( string input, double time ) {
            var textTime = GetTimeFromText( input );
            return textTime.Add( GetTimeFromDouble( time ) );
        } 

        static void Main( string[] args ) {
            var totalTime = GetAddedTime( "8:30", 8.67 );
            Console.WriteLine( totalTime ); // 17.10
        }
    }
}
```